# Building a custom RandomSearchCV using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to build a custom K-fold RandomSearchCV from scratch. I understand how RandomSearchCV works and I'm trying to implement it from scratch on a randomly generated dataset. When I try to run the code I get the following error. I think it has to do something with how I've created groups in my `x_train` list. What is this error and its fix? :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-229cc493eeb9> in <module>
     41 
     42 classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
---> 43 RandomSearchCV(X_train,y_train, classifier, folds = 3)
     44 
     45 

<ipython-input-12-229cc493eeb9> in RandomSearchCV(x_train, y_train, classifier, folds)
     26             #classifier (K-NN)
     27             classifier.n_neighbors = parameter
---> 28             classifier.fit(x_train_group, y_train_group)
     29 
     30             #Predicton

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1128         """
   1129         if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree)):
-> 1130             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
   1131 
   1132         if y.ndim == 1 or y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    753                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    754                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 755                     estimator=estimator)
    756     if multi_output:
    757         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    572         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    573             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 574                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    575 
    576         if force_all_finite:

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Here's my implementation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import random
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


x,y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=2, n_informative=2, n_redundant= 0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=60)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,stratify=y,random_state=42)

def RandomSearchCV(x_train,y_train, classifier, folds):
    train_scores = []
    test_scores = []

    #1. Generating 10 unique values from given range
    params = random.sample(range(0, 50), 10)
    x_train_split = []
    y_train_split = []
    #dividing x_train into groups
    for i in range(0, len(x_train), int(len(x_train)/folds)):
        x_train_split.append(x_train[i:i+int(len(x_train)/folds)])
        y_train_split.append(y_train[i:i+int(len(y_train)/folds)])

    #3.for each hyperparameter that we generated in step 1 and dividing dataset into training and CV datasets:

    for parameter in params:
        trainscores_folds = []
        testscores_folds  = []

        for group in range(len(x_train_split)):
            x_train_group = x_train_split[0:group] + x_train_split[group+1:]
            x_cv_group = [x_train_split[group]]
            y_train_group = y_train_split[0:group] + y_train_split[group+1:]
            y_cv_group = [y_train_split[group]]

            #classifier (K-NN)
            classifier.n_neighbors = parameter
            classifier.fit(x_train_group, y_train_group)

            #Predicton
            y_pred = classifier.predict(x_cv_group)
            testscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(y_cv_group, Y_pred))

            y_pred = classifier.predict(x_train_group)
            trainscores_folds.append(accuracy_score(y_train_group, Y_pred))

        trainscores.append(np.mean(np.array(trainscores_folds)))
        testscores.append(np.mean(np.array(testscores_folds)))

    return trainscores, testscores

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
RandomSearchCV(X_train,y_train, classifier, folds = 3)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`x_train_group` is a list of arrays, which makes it 3-dimensional (as mentioned in the error). This does not work with fitting the classifier, as it expects 2-dimensional input. Try calling `np.concatenate(x_train_group)` to concatenate the folds and make it a 2-dimensional input.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you are using an array of three dimensions while the `classifier.fit()` method was expecting a two-dimensional matrix. all you need to fix this issue is to change your train/cv/test groups to be like the following:

```
for group in range(len(x_train_split)):
    x_train_group = np.concatenate(x_train_split[0:group] + x_train_split[group+1:])
    x_cv_group = x_train_split[group]
    y_train_group = np.concatenate(y_train_split[0:group] + y_train_split[group+1:])
    y_cv_group = y_train_split[group]
    ....
```

Comment: With your changes we are assigning only one group of data to x_train_group where as we need to assign n-1 groups to train for folds=n.

Comment: You're absolutely right... I've edited my answer. Now, it should work !!